# Is it possible to use transform and image draw coordinates together?

Tags: java

I am trying to transform a moving animated sprite to be a reverse of itself. The only way I know of do this is:

```
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.scale(-1, 1);
transform.translate(-sprite.getWidth(), 0);
g.drawImage(imageFromSprite, transform, null);
```

Because there seem to be no methods to enter coordinates with the transform it means I am unable to carry on running my code which moves the animated sprite around the screen.

**Is there a way of transforming an image and drawing it at specified coordinates?**

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might be possible with threading

Comment: What class is `imageFromSprite`? What `drawImage()` method is that? I can't find it on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write yourself a method that performs the transformation and accepts the coordinates as parameters.

ex:

```
public void doTransformAndDraw(int x, int y)
{
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    //transform.scale(-1, 1);
    transform.translate(-sprite.getWidth(), 0);
    g.drawImage(sprite, x, y, null);
}
```

I'm assuming that the transform.translate() method is actually doing the image reversal.

Comment: But won't I still have to pass the coordinates into the draw method eventually meaning I won't be able to transform? Could you possibly give an example?

Comment: I don't think that will work because transform.translate(-sprite.getWidth(),0); doesn't actually make any changes to the image. Only the image render through g.drawImage seems to actually apply the transform. However, extending Graphics2D and writing a new overload of g.transformAndDrawImage might work however I don't know how to look at the graphics code so I could write a custom draw method.

Answer (score 0):

Transforming the image doesn't affect your ability to position the image, as shown:

```
BufferedImage reversedImage = new BufferedImage(imageFromSprite.getWidth(),
        imageFromSprite.getHeight(), imageFromSprite.getType());

AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.scale(-1, 1);
transform.translate(-imageFromSprite.getWidth(), 0);

Graphics2D reversedImageGraphic = reversedImage.createGraphics();
reversedImageGraphic.drawImage(imageFromSprite, transform, null);

// top left is drawn at (0,60)
g.drawImage(imageFromSprite, 0, 60, null);
```

If you want to do animate a `BufferedImage`, these links should be of interest:

http://web.mit.edu/1.124/LectureNotes/images.html
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/javaImgObserverAndAnimGif/